# Combine multiple inner joined rows into one row with multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a Questions table and an Answers table that has 4 to 8 answers connected to one question. When I want to get a list of questions and their answers, I use the following code:

```
select q.QuestionID, q.Question, a.Answer
from Question as q inner join Answer as a
on q.QuestionID=a.QuestionID;
```

This gives me one row for each answer with the question being repeated on each row. However, I want to only get one row per question with the answers in separate columns. If possible, I'd like to also limit this to only 4 answers. If there are more than 4, the rest should just be ignored. This is however not as important.

The four answer columns would be named "Correct", "Wrong1", "Wrong2" and "Wrong3". The first one in the table (with the lowest AnswerID) is the correct one.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm guessing I should use row_number() over (order by) somehow, but I can't figure out how. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
select q.QuestionID, q.Question, 
   CASE <some field>
   WHEN <condition> THEN a.Answer
   END as Correct,
   CASE <some field2>
   WHEN <condition2> THEN a.Answer
   END as Wrong1
   ...
from Question as q inner join Answer as a
on q.QuestionID=a.QuestionID
group by q.QuestionID
```

You can group by question and define conditioned fields for the  "Correct", "Wrong1", "Wrong2" and "Wrong3" columns

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm really new to SQL and I get the grouping part but I don't really know how to do the conditions part. I'm guessing I should replace the <condition> and <some field> parts with something? Or should I just write it like that? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes. Replace them with ptoper expression. E.g. you shoudl somehow recognize whether the answer is correct (a.is_correct=1 or something like this)

Comment: The first answer with a certain QuestionID is always the correct one and the rest are wrong (order doesn't matter for these) so maybe I don't need a condition?

Edit: so I pretty much just want to put the answers in the order I get them for each question.

Comment: @Serpiton Yup, I got the error, but I resolved it by putting all the fields in the group by list.

Comment: @Serpiton MySQL allows this but you are right there could be some e.g. THEN min(a.Answer) or first(a.Answer) or someting which returns proper result. I just tried to express the idea

Comment: @StanislavL Could you help me write some condition that says:


when the answer is first, select as Correct;


when the answer is second, select as Wrong1;


when the answer is third, select as Wrong2;


when the answer is fourth, select as Wrong3;

Thanks! (sorry, I can't seem to be able to do line breaks)

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use? The syntax could be DB specific.

Comment: @StanislavL I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I have no MS SQL experience. Guess you can use ROW_NUMBER() somehow and combine wuth q.QuestionID to introduce a row_number_in_group artificial field to be used in there CASE row_number_in_group 
   WHEN 1 THEN a.Answer
   END as Correct,
   CASE row_number_in_group 
   WHEN 2 THEN a.Answer
   END as Wrong1

Comment: Or this way select q.QuestionID, q.Question, min(a.answer) as correct, max(a.answer) as wrong1, <some more condition> as wrong2

Comment: @StanislavL I appreciate the help, but I just can't get it to work.